# What is limiting expression formula and how to find it?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

[image]

How do I find the limiting expression formula for delta k using part (a)? For part (a) I got

$$F(k) = \frac1{ i(k_o -k) } \left( e^{ \frac{i a }2 (k_o - k) } - e^{ \frac{-ia}2 (k_o - k) } \right) \\
|F(k)|^2 = \frac1{(-k + ik_o)^2} \left( 2+2e^{ia(k_o -k)}\right)  $$

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use mathjax (click on edit in the other posts)

Comment: Part (b) meant to use the convolution theorem to prove $\hat{F}_a(k) \to 2\pi\delta(k)$ when $a \to \infty$ and $k_0= 0$

Comment: hi @reuns, thanks for the reply but how does as a goes to infinity, 
F^a(k)→2πδ(k)?? I have a hard time figuring this out..

Comment: @reuns, I realized I can simplify F(k) expression into 2sin(k0-k)*1/2 a)/(k0-k)) and if I let x= (k0-k), it becomes 2(sin(ax/2)/x) so how does when a→∞, It becomes F^(k)→2πδ(k)??